# Incorporate error bars to best-fit curve

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have managed to get mathematica to perform a best fit curve. However, I wish to add error bar to the curve, how do I do so?

Comment: [`NonlinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html?q=NonlinearModelFit) \\ Applications

Comment: Here ist a nice How to [Add Error Bars to Charts and Plots](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/AddErrorBarsToChartsAndPlots.html)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: searching on errorbar in the search field of this site reveals 59 hits...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculating the fit manually (because sometimes it's nice to see the steps).  Not sure if these are the specific errors (residuals) you want.

```
data = {{0.3, 5.9}, {0.5, 5.1}, {0.6, 6.8}, {0.7, 6.3}, {0.9, 8.1}};

MapIndexed[(X[First@#2] = #1) &, First /@ data];
MapIndexed[(Y[First@#2] = #1) &, Last /@ data];

{n = Length[data],
 ΣX = Sum[X[i], {i, n}],
 ΣY = Sum[Y[i], {i, n}],
 ΣXY = Sum[X[i] Y[i], {i, n}],
 ΣX2 = Sum[X[i]^2, {i, n}]};

Clear[a, b];
sol = N@First@Solve[{
     (* Normal equations for straight line *) 
     ΣY == n a + b ΣX,
     ΣXY == a ΣX + b ΣX2}, {a, b}];

a = a /. sol;
b = b /. sol;
Show[Plot[a + b x, {x, 0.2, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 10}}],
 ListPlot[data]]
```

[image]

```
(* Least-squares regression of Y on X *)
Array[(Yhat[#] = a + b X[#]) &, n];

Array[(e[#] = Y[#] - Yhat[#]) &, n];

Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"] ;

errorData = ErrorBar /@ Abs /@ Array[e, n];
plotData = Partition[Riffle[
    Transpose[{Array[X, n], Array[Yhat, n]}],
    errorData], 2];

Show[Plot[a + b x, {x, 0.2, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 10}}], 
 ListPlot[data, PlotMarkers -> Automatic], ErrorListPlot[plotData]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Chris. I'll try the codes out and modify it to fit my need.